# Can't Pass Parcelable via Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable, pass-data

I have two activities:

- ListViewActivity
- AddActivity

and one object class :

- todoObj

I have a list view in my ListViewActivity  activity and when I click add button this will initiate AddActivity . In AddActivity when user enters Title, choose date, time and the category I want AddActivity to  create a todo object and pass this back to the ListViewActivity.

Sorry I could not share the code itself, it always gives this error all the time so I uploaded on [github](https://github.com/recepinanc/seyswork) please check it out.

Sorry again.
Many thanks.

Comment: "it always gives this error" - which error?

Comment: When I log it I can't see any data passed to my ListViewActivity, I can't even see the Log in my ListViewActivity 's onActivityResult. I want to know how can I get the data and pass it to another activity and crate an object, add this object to my Arraylist and show it on the ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to fix **onActivityResult** method in ListViewActivity:

1. Because of you setting result code ADD_REQUEST_CODE in AddActivity "**setResult(ListViewActivity.ADD_REQUEST_CODE, intent);**", you should use "**if (resultCode == ADD_REQUEST_CODE) {**" in ListViewActivity not **RESULT_OK**.
2. You should receive intent from onActivityResult not ListViewActivity's intent. getIntent() gives ListViewActivity's intent. So use data variable:

   onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent **data**)

Final code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ADD_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == ADD_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.i("ListViewActivity", "Returned onActivityResult");
            TodoObj todoObj = (TodoObj) data.getParcelableExtra("EXTRA_TODO");
            Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, "" + todoObj.getmYear(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I've edited it and now it works!

Comment: ... and I highly recommend that you use [John Ericksen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/654187/john-ericksen)'s library to make parcelable object: [github.com/johncarl81/parceler](http://github.com/johncarl81/parceler).

Comment: I'm gonna check it ASAP!  :)